# How to create azure linux vm with managed disk using nodejs cli?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-managed-disk

As title suggest, I want to use

`azure vm create ...`

to create a virtual machine using managed disk, however I can't see good example on how to achieve that. Ignoring the --storage-account-name parameter will random a storage account for me, which is not what I want.

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use the new Azure CLI 2 that released recently?  It provides full support for managed disks.

Comment: Basically it will mean I need to rewrite all my automations with the new CLI, not a great investment. If there is no other choices then it is what it is, but I would hope the existing CLI can actually handle this given MS doesn't sound want to replicate the x-plat CLI anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a link to back that up, but I'm pretty sure its not available in the x-plat CLI.

Looking at the [x-plat CLI commit history](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/commits/dev/lib/commands/arm/vm), I can't seem to find a single commit mentioning Managed disks and help doesn't show anything like that.

Comment: The interesting part is it does have `azure managed-disk` for just managing the disk itself, but the vm provisioning part is a disaster thus far.